# r: Error: replacement argument is zero length

Tags: r

I try to add the values ​​of a vector by initializing as soon as there is a 0

ex: I have (0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1) and I am looking for that (0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2)

I extracted the column of my data.frame with my 0 and my 1

```
x <-as.numeric (as.array (base1 $ taring))
```

I then apply the function to it:

```
for (i in 1: 3334) {
  if (x [i]! = 0)
    x [i] <- x [i] + x [i-1]
}
```

But it returns the error to me:

```
Error in x [i] <- x [i] + x [i - 1]:
  replacement argument is zero length
```

Please someone can tell me where this error came from, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array indices in R start at `1`.  So, in your first iteration, when `i = 1`, `i-1` is `0` and your code fails.  The fix is simple:

```
for (i in 2:3334){
  if(x[i]!=0)
    x[i]<-x[i]+x[i-1]
}
```

To make your code a little more robust you might consider

```
if (length(x) > 2) {
  for (i in 2:length(x)){
    if(x[i]!=0)
      x[i]<-x[i]+x[i-1]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input is

```
x <- c(0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1)
```

You can get the output using `ave` as :

```
ave(x, cumsum(x == 0), FUN = cumsum)
#[1] 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2
```

Comment: Effectivement c'est beaucoup mieux, merci!